Generating input objects using Rust graphql_client
I am struggling to get a trivial example client to work using the graphql-client crate in Rust (https://github.com/graphql-rust/graphql-client).
I seem to be able to generate code for a simple query but I need to call a mutator first to generate a session token and I'm stuck there because the mutator takes an input object, which I can't generate.
The second #derive fails with the message
error[E0412]: cannot find type `ObtainJSONWebTokenInput` in this scope
  --> src/bin/graphql.rs:23:10
   |
23 | #[derive(GraphQLQuery)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `GraphQLQuery` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)



I tried adding another #derive to generate the input object but it fails saying there is no operation with that name.
Can anyone tell me what I am missing? I'm not familiar with Rust so it could be obvious to someone who is.
I have the following schema
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}

type Query {
    account(accountNumber: String!): Account
}

type Mutation {
    obtainKrakenToken(input: ObtainJSONWebTokenInput!): ObtainKrakenJSONWebToken
}

type ObtainJSONWebTokenInput {
    "API key of the account user. Use standalone, don't provide a second input field."
    APIKey: String                          
    "Email address of the account user. Use with 'password' field."
    email: String                           
    "Live secret key of an third-party organization. Use standalone, don't provide a second input field."
    organizationSecretKey: String           
    "Password of the account user. Use with 'email' field."
    password: String                        
    "Short-lived, temporary key (that's pre-signed). Use standalone, don't provide a second input field."
    preSignedKey: String                    
    "The refresh token that can be used to extend the expiry claim of a Kraken token. Use standalone, don't provide a second input field."
    refreshToken: String                    
}

type ObtainKrakenJSONWebToken {
    "The body payload of the Kraken Token. The same information can be obtained by using JWT decoding tools on the value of the token field."
    payload: GenericScalar!                
    possibleErrors: [PossibleErrorType]
    "A Unix timestamp representing the point in time at which the refresh token will expire."
    refreshExpiresIn: Int                   
    "A token that can be used in a subsequent call to obtainKrakenToken to get a new Kraken Token with the same access conditions after the previous one has expired."
    refreshToken: String                    
    "The Kraken Token. Can be used in the Authorization header for subsequent calls to the API to access protected resources."
    token: String!                          
}

type PossibleErrorType {
    "The error code that might be returned from the query/mutation."
    code: String                            
    "The error description that might be returned from the query/mutation."
    description: String                     
    "The error message that might be returned from the query/mutation."
    message: String                         
    "The error type that might be returned from the query/mutation."
    type: String                            
}

type Account  {
        id: ID!
        "A code that uniquely identifies the account."
        number: String                      
    }

scalar GenericScalar

This query
mutation obtainKrakenToken($input: ObtainJSONWebTokenInput!) {
  obtainKrakenToken(input: $input) {
    refreshToken
    refreshExpiresIn
    payload
    token
  }
}

and this program
use graphql_client::{GraphQLQuery, Response};
use std::error::Error;
use reqwest;

type GenericScalar = String;

#[derive(GraphQLQuery)]
#[graphql(
    schema_path = "src/schema.graphql",
    query_path = "src/getAccount.graphql",
    response_derives = "Debug",
)]
pub struct GetAccount;

#[derive(GraphQLQuery)]
#[graphql(
    schema_path = "src/schema.graphql",
    query_path = "src/obtainToken.graphql",
    response_derives = "Debug",
)]
pub struct obtainKrakenToken;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello world");
}

